# Websphere 6.1 JAAS Logout

Tags: websphere, logout, jaas

I have an WebApplication on WAS 6.1 using JAAS already working. Authenticates and authorizes in a orderly manner. But my logout page is not deauthorizing the principal. This application works correctly on JBoss an on Glasfish but not on WAS.

My logout page is just a simple JSP with this content.

```
<%System.out.println("principal is not null:"+(null != request.getUserPrincipal()));

if (null != request.getSession(false))
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
%><jsp:include page="/index.html" />
```

Am I missing something? I would preffer not to use any specific API from Webpshere but if it is absolutely needed I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To succesfully logout this code snippet is also needed:

```
try {
        com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityHelper.revokeSSOCookies(request, response);
     } catch(Exception e) {
        // catch all possible exceptions if you want or handle them separately
        out.println("JAASLogoutServlet: logout Exception = " + e.getMessage());
        throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IBM also implements a form called ibm_security_logout.  I've been using it on websphere 7.0, but it exist in previous version.  You can find more details my answer to my question :

[How do I logout from Java EE container managed security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628796/how-do-i-logout-from-java-ee-container-managed-security)

Answer (score 0):

On WebSphere 8.5.5 (maybe in older versions, too)  you can set custom property.

Security -> Global Security -> Custom properties

```
com.ibm.ws.security.web.logoutOnHTTPSessionExpire=true
```