# How do I logout from Java EE container managed security?

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, logout

I am working in websphere 7.0.  I use the security from the application server.  I would like to removing the association with the user, so user is redirected to the login page before accessing a secure resource (and request.getUserPrincipal() returns null).

I try :

request.getSession().invalidate();

but the  user principal is still associated.

How could I remove that association?

Comment: Is it an option to send a client side redirect HTTP 302 to the logout url? This could be done using Javascript or manipulating the HTTP response header.

Comment: How are you redirecting the client to the login page before they authenticate?  Is there a filter that checks if the request has a UserPrincipal?

Comment: I am using java security configure in the web.xml, the servlet container is redirecting access to protected ressources to the login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On websphere, a special logout form calles must be used :

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tsec_pofolo.html

Here what I am using :

```
<body onload="javascript:document.logout.submit()">
    <h2>Sample Form Logout</h2>
    <form METHOD=POST ACTION="ibm_security_logout" NAME="logout">
    Click this button to log out:
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="logoutExitPage" VALUE="/some url">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: No, it *must* not. As per the documentation it's just a convenience way to logout without the need to invalidate the "whole" session.

Comment: Invalidating the session was not working, the user principal was still present.  If you have a better way to do it, I would like to know.

Comment: ibm_security_logout is not just a shortcut for invalidating the session it does the following: 1. Clears the Lightweight Third Party Authentication (LTPA) / single sign-on (SSO) cookies 2. Invalidates the HTTP session 3. Removes the user from the authentication cache. Even if your session is invalidated when calling HttpSession#invalidate() it is not sufficient. Your LTPA cookie remains valid and allows you to access applications using SSO without login in, and that is why you must call ibm_security_logout.

Comment: Note that the "clears the LTPA SSO cookies" operation only sends the SSO cookies marked as expired back to the client browser, so it is the responsability of the browser to remove the cookie. IBM does not invalidate the SSO cookies because they can be used in other applications.

Comment: For me, This just goes to myUrl.com/ibm_security_logout which of course does not exist and gives an error  :/